# How to add header and footer in jspdf?

Tags: angularjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to add header and footer in jspdf. I had created a pdf using jspdf()

```
Var doc=new jspdf()
```

And added some static text using `doc.text()` method. Then I had used autotable to generate various customized tables according to dynamic data.

I had not used `doc.addPage()` method to generate a new page it is done by tables automatically.

My problem is that I have to insert header and footer to every page and have no idea how to do that.

Note that I had not use HTML to PDF module, I had done it just by the jspdf plugin.

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing differently then the header and footer example in the jspdf-autotable repository? And would be nice to the relevant code section as well that is generating the problem.

Comment: I have tried the header footer option from the autotable but it shows header and footer  in the first page only........i want it to display in all pages

Comment: Are you using addPageContent? Can you add the code you are using to the question?

Comment: @Simon Bengtsson the function which is written in repository is working fine with the first page but it does not shows header and footer on next pages......

Comment: here is my code...

Comment: yes i am using addPageContent inside a table but that table is limited to page one only.

Comment: var pageContent = function (data) {
                // HEADER
                doc.text("xyz", 21, 18);
                
                //doc.setFontSize(20);
                //doc.setTextColor(40);
                //doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                
                // doc.text("Report", data.settings.margin.left + 15, 22);
                
                // FOOTER
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 20, 
                    doc.internal.pageSize.height - 22, 24, 11)

                doc.text(str, 170, doc.internal.pageSize.height - 17);
            };